# Add custom field to product media gallery

Tags: magento2

I'm completely new to Magento, and I'm using Magento 2 as a backend api (graphql). I want to add custom `field` `tag` `checkbox` or anything to media information to filtering and showing them on custom porfolio gallery at the front-end.

[image]

Where should I get start?

I were tried to add new role, but only one role can be picked for a media at a time.